# Tratar retorno na classe em C#

Tags: c#, .net, propriedade

Tenho uma classe Mesa:

```
public class Mesa
{
   public int Cdmesa { get; set; }
   public int Flsituacao { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }       
}
```

Gostaria de retornar o **Status** com as seguintes condições:

> Se **Flsituacao** = 1 retornar **Status** "LIVRE"
>
> Se **Flsituacao** = 2 retornar **Status** "OCUPADO"

É possível fazer isso diretamente na classe?

Comment: Pode colocar outras partes relevantes da classe? Posso responder assim, mas será na "sorte".

Comment: A classe é bem grande e eu não consigo copiar pois esta em outro pc sem internet. O que mais seria relevante?

Comment: Eu falei partes relevantes. Eu dei uma resposta, mas só com isso não sei se está certa. Ou pode dar mais detalhes. Note que eu fiz o que parece ser o que quer, mas não é certo, não sei o que deve fazer com o `set`. Veja se acha que precisa mudar algo na resposta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

você pode definir um get;set; personalizado.

```
public class Mesa
{
    public int Cdmesa { get; set; }
    public int Flsituacao { get; set; }
    public string Status 
    { 
        get
        {
            switch (this.Flsituacao)
            {
                case 1: return "LIVRE";
                case 2: return "OCUPADO";
                default: return "SITUACAO NÃO ENCONTRADA"
            }
        }
        set
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case "LIVRE": this.Flsituacao = 1; break;
                case "OCUPADO": this.Flsituacao = 2; break;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

mas neste caso, o mais racional é usar um enumerador.

```
public enum MesaSituacao : int
{
    [Display(Name = "LIVRE")]
    Livre = 1,
    [Display(Name = "OCUPADO")]
    Ocupado = 2,
    [Display(Name = "RESERVADO")]
    Reservado = 3,
}

public class Mesa
{
    public int Cdmesa { get; set; }
    public MesaSituacao Flsituacao { get; set; }    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Depende do que você chama de diretamente na classe. Se for isso mesmo não tem como. Mas pode fazer na propriedade.

```
public class Mesa {
    public int Cdmesa { get; set; }
    public int Flsituacao { get; set; }
    public string Status { 
        get {
            if (Flsituacao == 1) return "LIVRE";
            if (Flsituacao ==  2) return "OCUPADO";
            return "RESERVADO";
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/LogicGet.cs).

Não vou chutar o que o `set` deve fazer já que a pergunta não diz o que é. Se tiver que mandar o texto e ele ter que *setar* o `Flsituacao` não vejo vantagem em ter os dois a não ser pensando para o futuro.

Comment: Realmente não tinha necessidade de implementar o SET e acabei tirando. As duas respostas estão certas. Valeu

Comment: @leopiazzoli imagino que ambas ajudam, mas como elas são diferentes só uma te atendeu melhor e foi o que você resolveu fazer, pode escolher qualquer uma das duas.

Comment: Ah, vi agora que já escolheu a outra.

Comment: Usei a resposta que tem SWITCH pra caso venha a adicionar mais situações no futuro. Mas também o SET era desnecessário. :)

Comment: @leopiazzoli Eu pensei em fazer, mas nesse caso da exatamente na mesma, a não ser pelo fato de ter um valor *default*, eu não o fiz porque na sua pergunta não consta isso, não consta o que deve fazer se vier um valor errado, se nunca pode vir um valor errado (que é o que eu considerei, pelo menso é o certo a fazer), ou seja, fui na lógica mais correta para o caso, de acordo com o descrito.